# How to enable 24bit true color support in Gnome terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, colors

According to [this page](https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728), Gnome Terminal supports 24bit true color. This is consistent [with Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Terminal#Colored_text).

When I run [`color-spaces.pl`](https://github.com/robertknight/konsole/tree/master/tests/color-spaces.pl) in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Gnome Terminal 3.6.2, the result is the following:

[image]

While there is no reference image, I imagine that those green strangely-shaped objects at the bottom indicate that the terminal is unable to print 24bit colors correctly.

How to enable 24bit support?

Comment: If you want a reference image, run in `xterm`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

24bit support is enabled by default **but** `gnome-terminal` has to be in version linked against `libvte >= 0.36` (as stated on the page you mentioned). Which unfortunetly is not the case in the latest ubuntu 14.04 (at the time of writing).

As a workaround you may try:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
```

Last step removes their ppa - it's optional but be carefull, there is whole gnome3 at that ppa.

Oh and the screen: [image]

Comment: Is there a way to check which version of libvte gnome-terminal was originally linked against? I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 and plan on upgrading to 15.10 and I believe that both use versions of libvte > 0.36. However, I'm still not getting truecolor support in my terminal.

Comment: I just noticed that gnome terminal itself is not linked against libvte: `ldd /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real | grep libvte` on my Ubuntu 15.04.  So I guess this is important: `ldd /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server | grep libvte` and `dpkg -l | grep libvte`.

Comment: I would have guessed after 2 years it should be in now, but well :(

Comment: I am sorry after doing this process, my terminal now shows wired characters after each space. How do i reverse the entire process? Thanks

Comment: @Eskinder `sudo apt install ppa-purge`, `sudo ppa-purge gnome3-team/gnome3-staging`, `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging`